# How do I check if code is being run from a nose-test?

Tags: python, nose

I have some code which is used in a unit test. However, the library it loads requires some data which isn't actually required for the nose-test, because that data is mocked out by the unit test. I'd like to protect the file-reads in the library so that they don't get called in the case of a nose test.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I can probably do something with sys.modules, or the initial command line, but I'd prefer something more elegant, if it exists.

Comment: What is a *nose test*?

Comment: It's a specific unit-test framework.

Comment: how about checking if some file exists, if it doesn't, then flag the code as 'nose-test' and prevent the load of such files.

Comment: I don't understand - if it's mocked out, why are the reads still happening? Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I can't really give an example better than "in the unit-test case I want to exclude this code"

The reason it's happening is that I need a class from a library, so I'm importing the library. That library is where the data is normally read, so the reads are there, but I don't actually need them to take place in the unit test case.

Comment: @BrianPostow: You shouldn't have to modify your code because of your tests. If you feel like you have to, it might suggest your design is bad.

Comment: Oh, the design is HORRIBLE. But I can't re-arrange the code until I have tests that confirm that when I re-arrange things I haven't broken anything.

Comment: Having just typed that, I realize that eventually, after I refactor, hopefully the entire problem will go away, so maybe just doing something stupid with sys.modules is the best way. Leave it ugly, so that I fix ALL of it later...

Comment: Too much work. eventually, I should factor out the parts that are relevant to tests into a library and data reading into a different place, but for now... meh.

Comment: Instead of making your code aware of being under test or not..either mock the functionality and/or make your code composable to accept the objects to use so they can be mocked in tests.

For mocking built-in functions like `open` you may check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289894/how-do-i-mock-an-open-used-in-a-with-statement-using-the-mock-framework-in-pyth

Comment: This question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341005/python-conditional-variables-based-on-whether-nosetest-is-running

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in comments, the structure of this code is a mess, and part of the point of the tests is to make sure that I don't break things when I refactor...

So, for now, (unless someone gives me a better answer), I'm using:

```
if 'nose' not in sys.modules.keys():
    <read the data>
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct approach would be to mock all code with side-effects (I'll assume that what you do not want) with empty mocks.

Given tested_module my_module:

```
def do_something_and_destroy_world():
    destroy_world()
    return None
```

Sample test file is:

```
import mock
import unittest

import my_module

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testSomethingUgly(self):
        with mock.patch('my_module.destroy_world', return_value=None):
            result = do_something_and_destroy_world()
            self.assertIsNone(result)
```

When tests are run, assertion will be correct, and `destroy_world` wouldn't be called - instead it'll get replaced with empty mock with fixed return value.

Comment: Nice. I don't think it would work as nicely in my current code because the messy code isn't actually in a method. Unless I can do a  with mock.patch around an import, and even then it would get messy... 

But it's good to know what the right way to do this is in sane code...